# How can I condense multiple "indexOf" conditions in a single "if" statement?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I have a function that I want to run when a specific URL path is visited, but there's other pages further down that path, where I don't want the script to run. For example:

```
website.com/names     **This is the only URL where the script should run**
website.com/names/24/places
website.com/names/648/groups
website.com/names/7340/questions
```

The number following "/names/" ranges in length between 1 & n, but the three latter examples are the only further paths the URL might take. I only want the script to run when a user is on the "website.com/names" page, without anything following "pages." As of right now, I have the function as an "if" statement based on document.URL.indexOf, but it feels a bit messy:

```
if(document.URL.indexOf("names") >= 0 && (document.URL.indexOf("places") == -1 && document.URL.indexOf("groups") == -1 && document.URL.indexOf("questions") == -1))
```

This works perfectly fine, but I have a nagging suspicion that there's probably a better/cleaner way to create the "if" statement. Is there a way to either condense my current line, or use different code that will do the same thing in a simpler way, without over-complicating things?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are cases regular expressions *should* be used :)

```
if (/names$/.test(document.URL))
```

This condition passes only when "names" is the last part of the URL, without anything following it. The `$` means matching the end of the string.

Comment: That works fantastically! I knew there was a better way to do this. ;) Thanks for the help!

Comment: isnt indexOf faster than regEx?

Answer (score 2):

Why not check for *names* being at the end of **document.URL** using

```
if (document.URL.indexOf("names") == len(document.URL)-5)
```

(unless len(document.URL) != 4 cannot be assumed...).

Comment: I think you would say `if (document.URL.indexOf("names") == document.URL.length-5)`

Comment: You are perfectly right, I mixed some Python syntax in here. Sorry.